# Different results using qt-faststart and "ffmpeg -movflags +faststart"

Tags: c++, c, ffmpeg, streaming

I have a set of videos generated by security cameras, which have the MOOV atom at the end of the file, like this:

```
ftyp (32 bytes)
free (8 bytes)
mdat (29647845 bytes)
moov (42054 bytes)
```

I want to serve these files using progressive downloads (pseudo streaming) and it's the only acceptable way to do it.

Knowing that I tried to use tools like `qt-faststart` or directly `ffmpeg` with the corresponding flags (`-movflags +faststart`). Other detail is that I'm running this on a low profile machine, and FFmpeg takes like 6~8 seconds to finish (even using `-c copy`) and the other tool results to be much more efficient since it only moves some bytes, taking less than a second to finish. The thing here is that `qt-faststart` produces a video that can't be pseudo streamed but `ffmpeg` does it. Here are some comparisons:

`ffmpeg`:

```
ftyp (32 bytes)
moov (42422 bytes)
free (8 bytes)
mdat (29647845 bytes)
```

`qt-faststart`:

```
ftyp (32 bytes)
moov (42054 bytes)
free (8 bytes)
mdat (29647845 bytes)
```

As you can see, FFmpeg adds some extra bytes on the MOOV atom, can anyone point me in some research direction? Thank you all.

Comment: You can look at the file in a hex editor, or a tool like mp4box to see the exact contents, But it probably just an optional field, or timestamp, or muxing library string. Its not something you need to care about.

Comment: It is because with the FFmpeg's output I can make a 'progressive download' which is not the case with the output of qt-faststart

Comment: the moov is before the mdat. Thats all that matters for progressive downloads. The moov size does not matter.

Comment: if the ` qt-faststart ` version is not working, then it means there is something wrong with the original file. Something that ffmpeg knows how to fix when you remix it.

Comment: @JuanIgnacioSánchez Test with `qt-faststart` from the current git master branch.

Comment: Ok, I will try that.

Comment: This is the one, isn't it? https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/blob/master/tools/qt-faststart.c

Comment: Same results using the master branch. A detail which I don't know if it is important is that in Safari, the video plays OK (progressive download is performed and such) while in Chrome it doesn't.